# Are app-related trademarks allowed as keyword for an app in the App Store?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I'm building an iOS 8 iPhone app that lets user upload photos to Facebook.
Can I set the term `Facebook` as a keyword for my app in iTunes Connect or will that lead to a rejection by Apple?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use trademarked words as keywords for your app:

> When choosing a keyword, don’t use competing app names, company or product names, or **trademarked names**. Avoid inappropriate or objectionable terms or irrelevant words such as celebrity names; all keyword submissions are reviewed by Apple.

<sup>Source: [iTunes Connect Developer Guide: First Steps: Identifying Your App in iTunes Connect: Set Up Searching and Browsing: Keywords: Get the Best Results](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW7); emphasis mine.</sup>